# How does PubMed obtain papers' metadata?

Tags: pubmed

I wonder how PubMed obtains papers' metadata.

In particular, I am interested in the metadata used for these filters: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%22Review%22[pt]

[image]

Comment: This seems like a rather specific question for the creators of NCBI/PubMed. I'd consider tweeting at them at @NCBI and/or emailing them at info@ncbi.nlm.nih.gov and reporting back to answer this for the rest of us :)

Answer (score 1):

The [Frequently Asked Questions about Indexing for MEDLINE](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/indexfaq.html) give some interesting insights:

> How is MEDLINE produced?
>
> MEDLINE is the product of many information specialists at the National
>   Library of Medicine: serials librarians who obtain journal
>   subscriptions and check in the individual journal issues; data review
>   specialists who assure the quality of all supplied and created
>   bibliographic citations; **biomedical subject specialists who analyze
>   the subject content of articles and index the concepts that are
>   discussed, using the Medical Subject Headings (MeSH) controlled
>   vocabulary**; and computer and information specialists who develop and
>   maintain the various systems, including the retrieval system. **Every
>   journal issue and article cited in MEDLINE has been reviewed and
>   inspected by many individuals.**
>
> Do you scan in the citations?
>
> Bibliographic citations in MEDLINE are currently created by two
>   different methods. Many journal publishers supply NLM with citation
>   and abstract data electronically, tagged with XML (Extensible Markup
>   Language) codes to identify different data elements. **Article citations
>   from print journals for which data are not supplied are created with a
>   combination of optical character recognition (OCR) and keystroking.**
>   Citations that are received electronically may still require a
>   considerable amount of human intervention to add supplementary data
>   and to make other data uniform.
>
> As an author, how should I select keywords so that my article is
>   retrieved in MEDLINE?
>
> The National Library of Medicine does not use author-assigned keywords
>   for MEDLINE indexing. The terms that are used are descriptors from
>   MeSH (Medical Subject Headings) – the National Library of Medicine’s
>   controlled vocabulary thesaurus. MESH includes more than 27,000
>   descriptors, most of which may be qualified with one or more of over
>   80 MeSH subheadings. In addition, indexed terms may be derived from
>   the more than 200,000 headings called Supplementary Concept Records
>   (SCRs); these records (representing chemicals and rare diseases) exist
>   within a separate thesaurus and are mapped to MESH descriptors. NLM’s
>   policy for indexing is to use the most specific terms possible which
>   best describe the content and substance of the indexed item.
>
> **Since early 2013, PubMed has displayed publisher-supplied keywords in
>   the KEYWORDS field of the abstract display**. Authors who wish to supply
>   those keywords using the MeSH vocabulary can consult the MeSH Browser
>   (available at http://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/MBrowser.html). They may
>   also use a tool called MeSH on Demand (available at
>   http://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/MeSHonDemand.html) that identifies MeSH
>   terms in text using the NLM Medical Text Indexer program. After
>   processing the text, MeSH on Demand returns a list of MeSH terms
>   relevant to the text that was input.
>
> If authors wish their articles to be retrieved by their preferred
>   terminology, they should ensure that these words appear in the title
>   or abstract, where they will be searchable as text words.
>
> What types of articles are selected to be indexed?
>
> **NLM indexes only the substantive content of journals selected for
>   MEDLINE indexing.** In journals selected for cover-to-cover indexing,
>   for instance, NLM does not index items such as book reviews or
>   abstracts.
>
> Furthermore, a number of journals are multidisciplinary and publish
>   articles about non-life science fields such as astronomy, geology,
>   mathematics, and the like. Other journals cover many aspects of a
>   subject field, including non-life science aspects (e.g., chemical
>   journals may contain articles about physical chemistry as well as
>   biochemistry). **Because NLM indexes only articles that pertain to the
>   life sciences, articles in these selectively indexed journals that do
>   not pertain in any way to the life sciences are considered “out of
>   scope” and appear as unindexed citations in PubMed.**
>
> What is a Publication Type? How does it differ from descriptors?
>
> **> Since 1991, Publication Types (PTs) have been assigned by NLM indexers**
>   to describe the form of presentation of materials that are indexed.
>   Some PTs reflect the format and editorial practices of the individual
>   journal; others reflect the indexer's analytical judgment. Items
>   indexed prior to 1991 have had a limited number of PTs added by
>   machine rather than by re-indexing.
>
> PTs such as "letter" or "editorial" are determined by the style or
>   section heading used by the journal. "Letter" is assigned to routine
>   letters to the editor as well as to lengthier articles if the journal
>   labels them as "scientific correspondence" or similar caption.
>   Likewise, some journals label lead articles as "editorial," while
>   others reserve this caption for expressions of opinion. NLM follows
>   the journal's practice and assigns the PT "editorial" rather than
>   "journal article" in both these cases. A "classical article" is one
>   that has been reprinted by a journal because of its significance; NLM
>   makes no independent determination of an article's "classical" status.
>
> A published item may be assigned more than one PT. The default PT is
>   "journal article"; however, a journal article may also be a "review"
>   or a "randomized controlled trial." Certain PTs never co-occur. For
>   instance, an item cannot be both a journal article and letter,
>   editorial, or news item.
>
> PTs should not be confused with Main Headings (MHs) or descriptors,
>   although many PTs have a corresponding MH. PTs describe the form of an
>   article; MHs describe its contents.
>
> Can NLM add recently adopted new terminology to my article published
>   several years ago?
>
> **NLM does not re-index articles as new terms are added to the MeSH
>   vocabulary**. New terms are transparently linked to existing terms as
>   they are added so that searchers using the new terms will retrieve the
>   older citations.
>
> What online journals are indexed for MEDLINE? What journals have
>   online versions?
>
> Electronic, or online, journals come in two basic types: journals that
>   are online only and those that are published both in online and print
>   formats. Of the latter, many titles have identical content in both
>   formats; some have content unique to the electronic medium. The ISSN
>   that displays on the MEDLINE citation reflects the version of the
>   title from which NLM indexes the issue (print or online). Currently,
>   about 81% of journals indexed for MEDLINE are indexed from the online
>   version; a list of these journals is available at
>   http://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/journals/online.html.
>
> Who are the indexers, and what are their qualifications?
>
> **> Most MEDLINE indexers are either Federal employees or employees of
>   firms that have contracts with NLM for biomedical indexing**. A
>   prospective indexer must have no less than a bachelor's degree in a
>   biomedical science. A reading knowledge of certain modern foreign
>   languages is typically sought. An increasing number of recent recruits
>   hold advanced degrees in biomedical sciences. **Federal employees must
>   be United States citizens, but citizenship is not mandatory for
>   contractors.**
>
> Indexers are trained in principles of MEDLINE indexing, using the
>   Medical Subject Headings (MeSH) controlled vocabulary as part of
>   individualized training. The initial part of the training is based on
>   an online training module (partially available to the public at
>   http://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/indexing/index.html), followed by a period
>   of practice indexing. NLM does not accept other indexing training
>   programs as a substitute.
>
> **> About 1% of MEDLINE indexing is performed by indexers at the
>   International MEDLARS Centers in Sweden and Brazil.**
>
> How can I become an indexer?
>
> Indexing vacancies at the National Library of Medicine are filled
>   competitively. Any such vacancy is listed on NLM's Web site. Indexers
>   generally are classified as Technical Information Specialists, in the
>   GS-1412 job series. The normal career ladder goes from [GS-9 to GS-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Schedule_(US_civil_service_pay_scale)).
>
> For information about applying for work as an indexer with NLM's
>   contractors, please contact the Index Section for a listing of all
>   firms with a current indexing contract.
>
> I've heard that I can do indexing work at home. How do I apply for
>   this type of position?
>
> Contract indexers work from their homes once their training has been
>   completed. Indexers who are Federal employees may qualify to telework
>   for two or three days each week under the NIH Telework Program. See
>   the preceding paragraph for information on applying for either type of
>   indexing position.
>
> How can I apply for a job as an abstract writer for MEDLINE?
>
> **> No original abstracts are created for MEDLINE. Author abstracts in
>   English published in a journal are input for MEDLINE.**
>
> How can I apply for a job as a translator with the Index Section?
>
> **> Although journals from many languages are represented in MEDLINE, the
>   National Library of Medicine does not translate the articles.** Indexers
>   who perform subject analysis of the articles typically have a reading
>   knowledge of scientific terminology in one or more foreign languages.
>   They read and comprehend the articles, but they do not need to
>   translate them in order to index them.

Regarding MESH terms, it's highly possible that the human indexers uses the [NLM Medical Text Indexer (MTI)](https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/MTI/index.shtml) for suggestions.

[image]

[Use of MeSH in Indexing](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/intro_indexing.html) contains a bit more information but I wish the reference paper was a bit more recent than 1978.

> The MeSH vocabulary is designed for use by NLM to index the MEDLINE
>   database of journal citations and other media, and to search the
>   MEDLINE data using PubMed. The following outlines how MeSH is used by
>   indexing of the MEDLINE journal articles. For more detailed
>   information see Bachrach and Charen (1). See also [Use of MeSH in Online
>   Retrieval](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/intro_retrieval.html) and [Use Of Medical Subject Headings For Cataloging](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/tsd/cataloging/MeSH_CatPractices.html).
>
> 1. Combining specific MeSH Descriptors to index complex subjects: Co-ordination
>
> Rather than creating a MeSH Descriptor for every subject that might
>   discussed in a journal article, multiple MeSH Descriptors or
>   Qualifiers are combined to index the desired subject. For example,
>   **jejunitis may be expressed by the use of the Descriptors Jejunum and
>   Enteritis**. Similarly, MeSH Qualifiers can be used in conjunction with
>   appropriate Descriptors. For example, a deficiency of monoamine
>   oxidase may be indexed by the Descriptor Monoamine Oxidase, combined
>   with the Qualifier /Deficiency. This combining procedure is called
>   **"coordinated" indexing.**
>
> Note that not all complex subjects are indexed by co-ordination. When
>   a particular complex subject occurs frequently, a "pre-coordinated"
>   Descriptor may be created. For example, for a subject of arm injuries,
>   instead of combining the Descriptor Arm with the Qualifier /Injuries,
>   the single Descriptor Arm Injuries is used.
>
> 2. Multiplicity
>
> **Articles may discuss multiple subjects in which case indexers supply
>   Descriptors for all subjects.** For example, "an article in an
>   endocrinology journal does not relieve the indexer of covering the
>   non-endocrine aspects of the text." (Bachrach and Charen, p. 25)
>
> 3. Specificity
>
> **Indexers generally use the most specific MeSH subject heading
>   available**, rather than each of the broader subjects in which a
>   searcher may be interested. For example, an article about pulmonary
>   pathology is indexed under the Descriptor Lung rather than the more
>   general Respiratory System. The reasons for indexing to the most
>   specific are: (a) it records more information, and (b) it avoids
>   multiple, redundant, indexing since the broader subjects are linked to
>   the more specific subjects by the hierarchical MeSH Tree Structures.
>   For example, in PubMed a search for Respiratory System by default
>   includes articles indexed to Lung and other more specific Descriptors.
>
> (1) Bachrach, C. A. and Charen, Thelma. "[Selection of MEDLINE contents,
>   the development of its thesaurus, and the indexing process.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/359959)" Med
>   Inform (Lond). 1978 Sep;3(3):237-54. Note especially "Indexing
>   principles, pp. 250ff.

[MTI First Line (MTIFL) Indexing](https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/MTI/MTIFL.shtml):

> **MTI First Line (MTIFL) indexing partially automates the standard indexing process at the US National Library of Medicine.** MTIFL
>   provides the initial indexing for a citation. A human indexer then
>   reviews this indexing and modifies it as required by adding any missed
>   terms, removing any incorrect terms, and supplying Publication Types.
>   The process of the human curation of MTIFL results is called MTIFL
>   Completion.
>
> **In 2010, the Indexing Initiative team and the NLM Index Section conducted a series of three experiments with MTI to determine the
>   feasibility of using MTI recommended MHs as first-line indexing for
>   selected subject areas.** Journals for the three experiments were
>   chosen from fields where MTI was performing well (for example,
>   Microbiology, Anatomy, Botany, and Medical Informatics). The
>   experiments measured the accuracy of MTI indexing and the amount of
>   time required to index and revise both the manual and MTI First Line
>   (MTIFL) Completion. The results of the experiments showed that MTIFL
>   Completion was successful given the right circumstances, namely
>   journals with a low potential for the need of manually created
>   chemical flags and GeneRIFs that are normally added by the indexer. In
>   the case of MTIFL, the burden of creating the chemical flags and
>   GeneRIFs would shift to the reviser which would be time consuming and
>   undesirable.
>
> **In February 2011, fourteen journals were included in a pilot evaluation of MTIFL Completion. Since that time, almost 400 journals
>   have been selected for indexing by MTIFL Completion, and new journals
>   are added each month.** The process of evaluating journals for
>   indexing by MTIFL Completion is ongoing and dynamic, with journals
>   added and removed based on continued refinement of the evaluation
>   criteria and experience with MTIFL Completion results. One outcome of
>   the MTIFL experiments was that the timing information showed it took
>   indexers longer to remove wrong MTI recommendations than to add
>   missing ones. In talking with the indexers, the reason for this extra
>   time when removing a bad recommendation is that they have to take time
>   and decide if they missed something in the article or not before
>   removing it. So, MTIFL journals are processed with MTI's Balanced
>   Recall/Precision Filtering option providing a smaller, more precise
>   indexing list than with the regular MTI processing. The average F1
>   measure increases by 0.1252 (2015) when journals are incorporated into
>   the MTIFL program. This increase is likely due to the extra filtering
>   and indexing policies specific to MTIFL Completion.

https://ii.nlm.nih.gov/MTI/MTIFL_Journal_List.pdf:

[image]

I would be interested to see the F1, recall, and precision

---

Also of interest:

- [MEDLINE Indexing Online Training Course](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/bsd/indexing/training/USE_010.html)
- [Introduction to MeSH - 2016](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/introduction.html)